# Security update for MVC 3.0.0.0 did not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I see that Windows Update has installed the security update KB2972107 for MVC 3.0.0.0, but I do not see the new assembly or publisher policy in the GAC.  Windows Server 2008 R2, .NET 4.5, MVC 3

UPDATE:
I uninstalled the update and reinstalled using WU and no effect.

UPDATE:
I was looking for the wrong KB.  I should have been looking for KB2993937.  I would still like to know why this update has not automatically installed.

UPDATE:
SE's blocked the update with WSUS... nevermind question can be closed.

Comment: What did you look for and what operating system are you using?

Comment: As the question says, I looked for the new assembly and the publisher policy. As the question says, Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You could delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update worked fine.  I had the wrong KB number.  Sys admins had blocked the MVC update.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some days ago.
To fix it I downloaded Mvc library from NuGet Manager and kept using 4.0 version.

Font: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

Comment: FYI, using the nuget package for MVC seems like a good thing.  I can only download MVC 3 as version 3.0.0.1 for example.  If my project is set up with MVC 3.0.0.0 then it doesn't compile.  The MVC 3 nuget package fixed that problem.

Comment: Nuget has nothing to do with apps that are already in production on a server.